# Insert post and images in one only record

Tags: laravel

I have a posts table, with a image field inside it, and here is my problem. I need check that the user insert or not one image and if he user does,  insert the image with the other fields. Actually with my code, first insert the posts(titulo, contenido y url) and if the image exists, to insert the image, but the problem is that that generates me two records , one for the posts fields(title, content and url) and the second with the image field.

How can to do it, using create

```
\App\modelos\post::create($datosaInsertar);
```

instead of save()?

```
$posts= new \App\modelos\post();
 $posts->titulo= $request->titulo;
$posts->contenido= $request->contenido;
$posts->imagen= $request->imagen;
$posts->save();
```

STORE CONTROLLER

```
  public function store(Request $request)
        {




/****************************CREACION POST*********************************/
                $nombreimagen = 'mesteban_'.time().'.'.$request->file('imagen')->getClientOriginalExtension();
               $datosaInsertar = 
               array(
                    'titulo' => $request->titulo,
                    'contenido' => $request->contenido,
                    'url' => str_slug($request->titulo),
                    );
               $creandoPost = \App\modelos\post::create($datosaInsertar);
                 \Session::flash('estado','El post de nombre ..:: '.$request->titulo.' ::.. ha sido creado correctamente');

                /********************FIN CREACION POST**************/

                 /************************CREACION IMAGEN**************/


                 $ruta = public_path('ima\posts\\');


               if($nombreimagen):
                   $request->file('imagen')->move($ruta,$nombreimagen);

             \App\modelos\post::create(array('imagen'=> $nombreimagen));
                endif;
         /************************FIN CREACION IMAGEN*********************/

                return redirect()->to('/admin/posts');
            }
```

MODEL POST

```
<?php

namespace App\modelos;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class post extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $fillable = ['titulo','contenido','imagen','url'];

}
```

Sorry for my horrible english

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is pretty simple

Edit the second call to create function

```
   $creandoPost->imagen=$nombreimagen;
   $creadonPost->save();
```

The $creadonPost from the first create holds a reference to the insert operation which can be manipulated you can even retrieve the insert id from this variable like so

```
      $creadonPost->id
```